# I cannot push changes to my GitLab repository

Tags: gitlab, push

I was not pushing changes to GitLab.com repository for a while (about 4 months) and now I get the error: `The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.`. However, I'm the administrator and only user of that repo. I can login into the repo.

This is how I push the data:

`push -u origin master`

and the origin URL is of the form: https://gitlab.com/some-project/some-repo.git

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of gitlab-ctl status ?
Maybe you should restart your Gitlab

Comment: I don't have GitLab installed. The repo is hosted in GitLab.com.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's my bad. The user of the repo was other than the one I was trying (a palm face emoji should be shown here instead :).